# Relation between cone radius and distance from cone apex

Tags: integration

I am stuck on the following problem;

> Let a cone with height $h$ and base area $B$ have the density $\rho (x) = \rho_{0} \frac{3x^{2} + 2xh}{h^2}, 0 \leq x \leq h$
>   Where $x$ is the distance from the cone apex and $\rho_{0}$ is a real constant.
>
> (a) Show that the relation between cone radius $y$ and distance from cone apex $x$ is given by: $y = (\frac{B}{\pi h^{2}})^{2}x$

I would really appreciate a pointer on where to get started. Is the information regarding density relevant here? I know how to use it later on where i'm asked to find the cone's mass.

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: I suspect that you may have mixed up $x$ with $y$...

Comment: I get $y = \sqrt{\frac{B}{\pi}} \frac{x}{h}$.  Use similar triangles.

Answer (score 2):

The density is not relevant, since at this point it's pure geometry. I assume we're talking about a right cone, otherwise this doesn't make any sense.

To prove the equation given in the question, look at the cone from the side - suddenly it becomes an isoceles triangle. What's the base of the triangle? What's the height? Now drop down a perpendicular from the top of the triangle to the base, which it will bisect. Pick a point on that perpendicular, and mark it as being distance $x$ from the apex. Draw the perpendicular at that point. The base of the right triangle formed by that perpendicular is of length $y$. Now do you have any similar triangles? Can you relate $y$ and $x$ to the base and height of the larger triangle, and hence to $B$ and $h$?

Comment: I'm not getting anywhere with this... I can see that I have similar triangles but I don't know how to relate y and x to the larger triangle. Don't I need some scale factor?

Comment: You don't need to explicitly calculate the scale factor, you just need to know that when you identify pairs of corresponding sides in the two triangles that the ratio of their lengths is the same. So y/base of big triangle = x/height of big triangle.